# Typeahead duplicate records

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, typeahead.js, typeahead

I'm using `typeahead` in my rails app like this:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], id: "search" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<%end%>

<script>
var items = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: '/items/autocomplete?search=%SEARCH',
        wildcard: '%SEARCH'
    }
});


$('#search')
    .typeahead(null, {source: items})
    .on('typeahead:selected', function(e){
        $("#search-form").submit();
    }).focus();
</script>
```

controller action:

```
def autocomplete
  render json: Item.search(params[:search], {
    fields: ["title"],
    match: :word_start,
    limit: 10,
    load: false,
    misspellings: {below: 5}
  }).map(&:title)
end
```

The autocomplete works fine but it shows duplicate results. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @dbugger thanks for the reply, I just added the controller action to my question.

Comment: no idea where the doubles come from (apparently they're in your database), but you could add a 'uniq' to get rid of them...

Comment: Thanks for the rely @Danny, how exactly can I do that?

Comment: I would insert it just before the .map call in your autocomplete method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @danny basically suggested, with `.uniq` used after the map.

```
def autocomplete
  render json: Item.search(params[:search], {
    fields: ["title"],
    match: :word_start,
    limit: 10,
    load: false,
    misspellings: {below: 5}
  }).map(&:title).uniq
end
```

Comment: unfortunately I still get duplicate titles. Btw I do have multiple `items` in my db with the same title, Its seems like each item a create a new title is added on the typeahead dropdown. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: it works fine!! thanks!! change the answer so I can accept it!